I'm having problem in stripe payment settings when I want to redirect to payment gateway page. What should I do?
The problem is like this : 'Unrecognized request URL (GET: /v1/checkout/sessions/). If you are trying to list objects, remove the trailing slash. If you are trying to retrieve an object, make sure you passed a valid (non-empty) identifier in your code.'
Controller:
public IActionResult OrderConfirmation(int id)
{

    OrderHeader orderHeader = _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.Get(u => u.Id == id, includeProperties: "ApplicationUser");
    if (orderHeader.PaymentStatus != SD.PaymentStatusDelayedPayment)
    {
        var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();
        Stripe.Checkout.Session session = service.Get(orderHeader.SessionId);

        if (session.PaymentStatus.ToLower() == "paid")
        {
            _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.UpdateStripePaymentID(id, session.Id, session.PaymentIntentId);
            _unitOfWork.OrderHeader.UpdateStatus(id, SD.StatusApproved, SD.PaymentStatusApproved);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }
    }

    List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCarts = _unitOfWork.ShoppingCart
        .GetAll(u => u.ApplicationUserId == orderHeader.ApplicationUserId).ToList();

    _unitOfWork.ShoppingCart.RemoveRange(shoppingCarts);
    _unitOfWork.Save();



    return View(id);
}

Model:
public class OrderHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public ApplicationUser? ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShippingDate { get; set; }
    public double OrderTotal { get; set; }
    public string? OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string? PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    public string? TrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Carrier { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public DateOnly PaymentDueDate { get; set; }

    public string? SessionId { get; set; }
    public string? PaymentIntentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PostalCode1 { get; set; }

}



I tried to look for the same error but there are different codes written which is not appropriate for my solution.

When you say you are having trouble with Stripe payment settings, do you mean the Stripe Payment settings in the dashboard(https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/checkout)?
Based on the screenshot it looks like someting is amiss with your Checkout Session retrieval call (https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve?lang=dotnet).  For that I recommend logging the value for the Session ID just before you attempt to retrieve it to make sure it is what you expect.

Are you using/developing against the "old", legacy ASP.NET (on .NET), or are you targetting ASP.NET Core (on .NET Core) ? Those are similar - but not identical - and you've tagged both in your question.....

Even though this is a Test mode key, you should remove your API key immediately and probably roll it following this guide: https://docs.stripe.com/keys#rolling-keys
Never ever post your secret keys, ever.

The error message is actually quite helpful.  The "No such X" error means that you are attempting to access a Stripe object that does not exist on the account you are making the API request for.    This often occurs for users with Stripe Connect (where objects can be created on different accounts).  Check to make sure the session you are retrieving actually exists on the account whose API keys you are using.

@marc_s I am targetting ASP.NET Core MVC. Sorry about that, I can remove ASP.NET section.

@RyanM Thank you, the error exactly occurs because of that, I removed the key section that I've shared. However I couldn't find a solution on how to rewrite the session. I've looked for the docs available.
